# Fast way to compute entropy distribution in python with pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a pandas DataFrame of percentages, e.g.:

```
Feature    Sample1    Sample2     ...
feat_1     0          .5
feat_2     .2         .4
feat_3     .7         .6
...
```

There are two classes in the original problem. For each feature, sample, the value represents the percentage of the first class (the percentage of the second class is just the complement, `1-perc`).

I want to compute the [entropy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html) distribution for each feature, i.e.:

- For `feat_1` the distribution will be composed by minimum entropy (0) for `Sample1`, by maximum entropy for `Sample2`, etc..
- For `feat_2` and `feat_3` the first two values of entropy will be intermediate

My approach is the following:

- Since `scipy.stats.entropy` requires the probability of each class, and I have two classes, I duplicate each column (sample) into percentage column (original column) and complementary percentage column (1 - original column)
- Compute entropy for each pair of column (each sample), per feature

Right now I'm using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as ss

n_samples = 1000

# duplicate each column into percentage column and complementary percentage column
df = pd.concat([df, 1 - df], axis=1)
df.columns = [f'{sp}_{cl}' for cl in ['pos', 'zer'] for sp in range(n_samples)]

# compute entropy for each pair of columns
entropy = pd.concat([df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith(str(s) + '_')].apply(ss.entropy, axis=1) for s in range(n_samples)], axis=1)
```

Is there a way to optimize this code using built-in `pandas` API? I could parallelize using joblib but I would prefer built-in methods.